# VisualForce: Pass a parameter to a custom component inside a repeater

Tags: salesforce, custom-component, apex-code, visualforce

I can't figure out why this isn't working:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!MyContacts}" var="c" >
    <c:ContactRowComponent contactLastName="{!c.LastName}"/>  
</apex:repeat>
```

(where on the main controller MyContacts returns an array of Contact objects, and on the component contactLastName is defined as a String attribute)

This gives me error:

`Literal value is required for attribute contactLastName in <c:ContactRowComponent> at line 25 column 27`

It seems to be saying that a literal value is required and not a formula? Is what I am trying to do impossible, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Should be ok :( Is myContacts really array (Contact[]) or something else? Should be an array. Also - stupid but are you sure you don't declare "c" variable as something else anywhere before? Are you sure you query for the "LastName"? What happens if you comment out the component and just display the {!c.LastName} merge field?

Answer (score 2):

I have come across this issue as well. In my case it was because I specified the default attribute in the component attribute which you can't do on fields that use a formula for some reason.

For instance this will produce the error you described when passing in a formula value:

```
<apex:attribute type="string" name="value" default="sometext" description="some name value" />
```

So if you remove the default attribute the error will be resolved. Let me know if this solves for your particular use case.